# Problem about convex sets and convex functions

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

DEFINITION: Let $X$ a normed space, $K\subseteq X$ a convex set and 
$f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We say that $f$ is convex if when $a,b\in K$ and 
$0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1$ then $f(ta + (1-t)b) \leqslant tf(a) + (1-t)f(b)$

PROBLEM:

Let $X$ a normed space, $K\subseteq X$ a convex set, 
$f: K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is convex and 
$x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots , x_{n} \in K$, $t_{1}, t_{2}, \ldots, t_{n} \geqslant 0$, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k} = 1$, proof that 
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}x_{k}\in{K}\,\,$ and
$\,\,f\left({\sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}x_{k}}\right) \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^{n}t_{k}f(x_{k})$

Could someone give me a suggestion to solve this problem, or if there is, some geometric interpretation that will help me solve the problem?

Comment: Hint: use induction to extend the definitions (of convexity of a set and convexity of a function) from a statement about two points to a statement about $n$ points.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Look at the point $y=\frac{t_1}{1-t_3-...-t_n}x_1+\frac{t_2}{1-t_3-...-t_n}x_2$. This point is in $K$, since $\frac{t_1}{1-t_3-...-t_n}+\frac{t_2}{1-t_3-...-t_n}=1$. Now apply, the convexity property for one less point to $y,x_2,...,x_n$ and coefficients $(1-t_3-...-t_n), t_3,t_4,...,t_n$.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, I have already solved the problem.